# Disable language(LTR) for a particular screen in android app

Tags: android, kotlin

Can we disable RTL for a particular screen in android app for Arabic language?Means, even if we select Arabic language, particular screen show english text and other screen Arabic (as per locale) and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `android:layoutDirection` property in XML layout for the activity/fragment, it can have either rtl or ltr values. This will override the applications setting for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the layout direction for that screen as ltr as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layoutDirection="ltr">

your code 

</RelativeLayout>
```